# twin column article in bookdown

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I am using bookdown::pdf_document2 and I would like to create an article with 2 columns. I am using bookdown to be able to do section referencing.

I used `pandoc_args: [
 "-V", "classoption=twocolumn"` but that made it ignore the font and default to computer modern. Is there a way to get 2 columns articles with pdf_document2 ?

I am using the following header:

```
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    fig_crop: no
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 5
fontsize: 12pt
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
sansfont: Source Sans Pro
mainfont: Source Sans Pro
mathfont: Calibri
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the classoption within the YAML header:

```
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    fig_crop: no
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 5
fontsize: 12pt
editor_options:
  chunk_output_type: console
sansfont: Liberation Sans
mainfont: Liberation Sans
classoption: twocolumn
---
```

I changed the font to one that's available on my system.